# Somewhat complicated limit (no l'Hopital permitted)

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to calculate the following limit:

$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
where
$$ f(x) = e^{-2x}(\cos(x)+2\sin(x))$$
and
$$g(x) = e^{-x}(\cos(x)+\sin(x))$$

Now, because $g'$ has zero points, we can't use the de l'Hopital rule, but when I draw the graph, it does seem that de l'Hopital would produce a valid  answer ($0$).

How would I go about calculating this limit? (My intuition says it doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

L'Hôpital's rule is not normally used when finding a limit as an expression tends to $\infty$.

In your case, 
$$
g(x)=e^{-x}(\cos(x)+\sin(x))=\sqrt{2}e^{-x}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)
$$
so $g$ has zeroes at $-\frac\pi4,\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}4,\dots$.  Therefore, the expression
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
is not defined at these points.  Indeed, since $f$ *does not have* a zero at $-\frac\pi4,\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}4,\dots$, there is no way we could make $f/g$ into a continuous function even if we wanted to.  So there is no limit as $x\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $\tan x = -\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $f(x) = 0$, and if $\tan x = -1$ then $g(x) = 0$. Thus the ratio $\dfrac fg$ alternates between $0$ and undefined infinitely often as $x \to \infty$ and can't have a limit.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{e^{-2x}(\cos x + 2 \sin x)}{e^{-x}(\cos x +  \sin x)}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt 5(\cos x - \tan^{-1}(2))}{\sqrt 2e^{x}\cos (x +  \pi/4)} = \text{does not exist}$$

Comment: Where the hell did you get that? :p

Comment: @SydKerckhove, get what?  are you  wondering how i got $a\cos x + b\sin x = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2}\cos (x - \phi)?$

Comment: That's probably what I'm wondering yes. Note that I'm taking an intro to analysis course. Also, excuse the language. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @SydKerckhove Any expression of the form $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$ can be written in the form $R\sin(x+\phi)$ and in the form $S\cos(x+\psi)$.  To find $R$ and $\phi$, or $S$ and $\psi$, use standard trigonometrical rules to expand out the expression $R\sin(x+\phi)$ (or the other one), put it equal to your original expression $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$, and solve the simultaneous equations you get.

Comment: In case that wasn't clear, check out http://www.mash.dept.shef.ac.uk/Resources/web-rcostheta-alphaetc.pdf .

Answer (score 2):

The limit does not exist because of the periodic root in the denominator (that does not coincide with a root in the numerator): it is such that for $x$ as large as you want, it will never be possible to bracket the function.